# Erro group by Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Quando tento fazer este group by no oracle ele me retorna mensagem dizendo que isto não é uma expressão group by

```
SELECT produto.cd_produto, produto.ds_produto, est_pro.cd_estoque,
      estoque.ds_estoque, fornecedor.cd_fornecedor,
      fornecedor.nm_fornecedor, prod_atend.cd_lote,
      prod_atend.dt_validade, est_pro.qt_estoque_atual,
      itent_pro.QT_ATENDIDA, ent_pro.nr_documento
 FROM produto, estoque, fornecedor, est_pro, prod_atend, ent_pro, itent_pro
WHERE produto.cd_produto = est_pro.cd_produto
  AND fornecedor.cd_fornecedor = produto.cd_ultimo_fornecedor
  AND prod_atend.cd_produto = produto.cd_produto
  AND estoque.cd_estoque = est_pro.cd_estoque
  AND ITENT_PRO.CD_ENT_PRO = ENT_PRO.CD_ENT_PRO
  AND ITENT_PRO.CD_PRODUTO = PRODUTO.CD_PRODUTO
  AND est_pro.cd_estoque = '15'
  group by produto.CD_PRODUTO, produto.DS_PRODUTO;
```

Comment: Para ficar mais fácil de outras pessoas lerem sua query, mantenha a mesma formatação de maiúsculas em todas as vezes que fizer referência a algum campo. Ainda, não respeitar maiúsculas/minúsculas como estão nos nomes dos campos, pode fazer a query incompatível com outros servidores, normalmente indesejável.

Answer (score 1):

Da documentação em https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.1.0/ref/rrefsqlj32654.html:

> SelectItems in the SelectExpression with a GROUP BY clause must contain only aggregates or grouping columns.

Ou seja, TODAS as colunas no seu select devem ser parte do GROUP BY ou então ter uma função de agregação como por exemplo `AVG()` ou `FIRST()`.

Isto porque o engine do banco não sabe que só existe um `est_pro.cd_estoque` para cada grupo que ele fizer, e se houver mais de um o que ele faz não é definido. Então pode-se usar, por exemplo `SUM(est_pro.cd_estoque)`. Isto vale para todas as colunas que quiser selecionar.

Comment: Não vi motivo para o "group by".

Answer (score 1):

Pedro pelo que vi no seu select você está tentando agrupar apenas pelo código e pela descrição do produto.
Porem na função group by você precisa colocar todos os campos que estão no select